# How to run KafkaManager (HTTP) and Zookeeper (TCP) processes on Bluemix PaaS

Tags: java, apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, apache-zookeeper, cloud-foundry

I have two processes (both Java) that I need to run as part of a single app.

1. Kafka-Manager: This process needs the http port which I can get from the $PORT environment variable.

https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager

2. Zookeeper: This process needs a TCP. By default, it is configured as 2181.

https://zookeeper.apache.org/

Which port should I specify to run Zookeeper on PaaS?

Here is my current setup:

[image]

Procfile has

`web: zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/zkServer;bin/kafka-manager -Dhttp.port=$PORT`

So with this setup, I am able to get Kafkamanager running. But it has no data, as it needs Zookeeper running as well. Hence I can't do anything with my app.

Here is part of my log trace

```
2016-04-18T15:32:21.706-0400[App/0]OUTjava.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2016-04-18T15:32:22.810-0400[App/0]OUT[[37minfo[0m] o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-04-18T15:32:22.811-0400[App/0]OUT[[33mwarn[0m] o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2016-04-18T15:32:22.811-0400[App/0]OUT at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361) ~[org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
2016-04-18T15:32:22.811-0400[App/0]OUTjava.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2016-04-18T15:32:22.811-0400[App/0]OUT at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
2016-04-18T15:32:22.811-0400[App/0]OUT at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081) ~[org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
2016-04-18T15:32:22.811-0400[App/0]OUT at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
```

So clearly, it can't connect to `localhost/127.0.0.1:2181`

How can I make this connection work?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but have you looked at the Message Hub service in the Bluemix catalog? It will run Kafka for you so maybe you don't need to run it yourself.

Comment: thanks, but KafkaManager is a monitoring tool for Kafka. It needs a Zookeeper instance to store the state. I dont want to use my orgs zookeeper cluster, which is overloaded as it is.